# Secondary constraint imposed gauge fields

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

I am asking about aspects of quantizing electromagnetic field followed in Weinberg's Quantum theory of fields Volume I, in section 8.2 . I am able to understand the primary constraint that arises from the fact that lagrangian density is independent of time derivative of $A_0$.

But the secondary constraint as stated it follows from the field equation for the fixed by the primary constraint is:

$$\partial_i\Pi^i=-\partial_i\frac{\partial\mathscr L}{\partial F_{i0}}=-\frac{\partial\mathscr L}{\partial A_0}.\tag{8.2.3}$$

where $\Pi^\mu$ is canonical conjugate momenta to the electromagnetic vector potential, which is given as:
$$\Pi^\mu\equiv \frac{\partial\mathscr L}{\partial(\partial_0A_\mu)} \tag{8.2.1}$$
and i runs over the values 1,2,3 in eqn. (8.2.3).

Now from the statement that field equation for the quantity fixed by primary constraint means
\begin{align}
\partial_\mu\frac{\partial \mathscr L}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_0)}&=\frac{\partial \mathscr L}{\partial A_0}\\
\partial_i\frac{\partial \mathscr L}{\partial(\partial_i A_0)} &= \frac{\partial \mathscr L}{\partial A_0} \tag{A}
\end{align}
While I am getting the value of $\partial_i\Pi^i$ is

$$\partial_i\Pi^i=\partial_i\frac{\partial\mathscr L}{\partial (\partial_0A_i)}$$

It will be helpful if any can explain how to obtain the result as given in the text?

Comment: There's not enough information here for anyone to be really able to tell what you're asking if one does not have access to Weinberg. How did you define the $\Pi^i$? How are you getting your result? Have you actually tried to compute these derivative to see whether they might be the same?